# Is it possible to clear the Scheduled Jobs page?

Tags: scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, ui

Having a demand that involves scheduling of several different classes at different times, the Scheduled Jobs page can get really polluted. This happens mainly because jobs that were executed are still displayed on the page.

Is there a way to clear executed jobs from the page? Or does Salesforce do this automatically after some time?

Comment: yes salesforc clear them after some time. I am not sure about exact days but it is 30 days.

Comment: Do you have a little more info on what you are trying to accomplish? Are you looking to have the ability to wipe it with a button click (much like the debug logs page does)? Are you looking to track a specific job, but are having trouble finding it amongst all the other jobs?

Comment: I just want a cleaner page to look at, if I have to check the scheduled jobs page. Some jobs are executed, and still appear in there.